# Replacing the Fragment in Tablayout Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I used the tablayout in my project. I have to replace the fragment in the tablayout. The code is like below

> Activity Class

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());




        adapter.addFragment(Fragment1, "One");
        adapter.addFragment(Fragment2, "Two ");
        adapter.addFragment(Fragment3, "Three");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

> Interface in Activity

```
@Override
    public void onInput(int input) {

        Here how to replace fragment three


    }
```

Comment: What is the question???

Comment: @PankajKumar when onInput method is called I would like to replace the fragment three in adapter and refresh the contents of fragment three

Comment: What is input here? Does it mean page number?

Comment: @PankajKumar No just string to send using bundle to the replacing fragment

Answer (score 0):

I think replacing the fragment is not a good idea. So I would like to show you another way to achieve what you want.

1. `viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);` you can use this method to change the page. Here position is page-number starting from 0 to total-pages - 1.
2. Use ViewModal to pass latest data (in your case *`"input"`*). So here you can set value from  `onInput(int input)` and in each fragment of ViewPager you can subscribe/ unsubscribe ViewModal to listen changes. In this way you do not need to replace fragment and the page which is on screen will get latest data and can show.